# Unable to receive and add Tor's keys to apt

Tags: debian, tor-install

I'm following [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) to install Tor on a Debian based machine.

However, I'm unable to add Tor's gpg key to the system's apt repository:

```
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
root@fenrir:~# gpg --keyserver sks-keyservers.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection refused
```

I'm unsure if the GPG keys of Tor are no longer available or if the key servers are down.

Comment: That looks like some kind of connectivity issue on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Works here, either the servers were down (unlikely) or you can't access them because they are blocked (e.g. Firewall)

You can import the key manually like this:

```
gpg --import PATH_TO_KEY
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

You can get the key [here](https://gist.github.com/pgerber/ac401aacb2375379716802c55042cdcb)